# Editing HTML elements using JS in other pages

Tags: javascript, html

How can I have a control on HTML elements using a JS code from another page, like, I have an HTML page called "index" and it contain a `<p>` element, and I have a another page called "controlPanel", how can I Edit the `<p>` element in "Index" from the "controlPanel" page.

Comment: You cannot do that, or you'll have to persist it in local storage or use libraries such as reactjs

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs in the context of the current page and is completely removed from memory along with HTML and CSS when the browser navigates from one page to another. So you cannot control one page using JavaScript from another page.

The only exceptions are:

1. If the first page opens the second page using the `window.open()` method.
2. If the second page is loaded in an `iframe` inside the first page.

What you can do is persist the state to some storage (e.g. the database, or the local storage in the browser) in the first page, and read it in the second page to change the behavior accordingly.

Of course, you can always send parameters from the first page to the second (e.g. in the URL query string), and the second page will behave differently according to the value of the parameters.